# Passing %f conditionally to apps in Exec command of custom desktop launchers

Tags: command-line, wine, launcher

I am trying to customize some desktop launchers for a couple of Wine apps. Namely foobar2000 and Winamp. What I would like to do is to drag-and-drop files/folders onto the launchers on my desktop and play them directly.
To that end, I edited the original launchers and appended a `Z:%f` argument to the `Exex` command, which worked just fine. For example:

`Exec=env WINEPREFIX="~/.wine" wine-stable C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix ~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/foobar2000.lnk Z:%f`

However, when I now try to launch the apps by double clicking on the desktop "shortcut", both foobar2000 and Winamp try to load 'Z:' (exhibiting different behaviors for each app, but with the same underlying problem).

How can I customize my launcher in such a way to only pass `%f` conditionally when it's not `null`? Maybe something along the line of (`cmd_arg = %f != null ? "Z:%f" : ""`) and then pass `cmd_arg` to `Exec`...

I tried looking into `command` and `eval` but I'm not sure if they can be incorporated within the `Exec` command, nor whether I can achieve what I want by using those commands.

What would be the standard way to go about this?